# Как сортировать товар по своему полю?

Tags: wordpress

вижу полно примеров для добавлении сортировки. Но мне нужно добавить свою. но не могу понять некоторые вещи. например $sortby['stock_list_asc'] stock_list_asc- откуда берется или это свое название?

```
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num wp_posts.ID';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '_stock';
```

и эти поля, желательно рассказать о них, окуда берется $args['orderby'] и $args['meta_key']. или направьте меня по ссылки на доки. мне нужно сделать по примеру но только на размер.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'stock_list_asc' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num wp_posts.ID';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_stock';
    }
    elseif ( 'stock_list_desc' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num wp_posts.ID';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_stock';
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['stock_list_desc'] = 'Остаток: по убыванию';
    $sortby['stock_list_asc'] = 'Остаток: по возрастанию';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в нижних подчеркиваниях, заменил на дефис стало норм.заменил  $sortby['stock_list_desc'] на $sortby['stock-list-desc'].

Comment: Ответ не информативный. В чем проблема? Что и где заменить?

Comment: Мне это не нужно. Вы создали тему на форуме, куда заходят тысячи пользователей. Если вы решили свой вопрос, то укажите решение в ответе и потом отметьте ответ, чтоб тема не оставалась открытой